# Startup.cs in ASP.NET 5 class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I created a ASP.NET class library in my ASP.NET5 application. I wanted to add `Startup.cs` file in order to load some configuration from .json (ConnectionString) file to use it in project and add it to DI. Then I wanted to inject `AppSettings` into my `DbContext` which is in the same project. But this is not working, it seems code in Startup class is never executed.

Injecting `AppSettings` into `DbContext` throws Exception

```
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Beo.Dal.Properties.AppSettings' while attempting to activate 'Beo.Dal.DataContexts.ApplicationDbContext'.
```

DbContext

```
private static bool IsCreated;
private AppSettings AppSettings;

public ApplicationDbContext(AppSettings settings)
{
    AppSettings = settings;
    if (!IsCreated)
    {
        Database.AsRelational().ApplyMigrations();
        IsCreated = true;
     }
 }
```

Did I miss somthing or I got it all wrong? I already got one `Startup.cs` in MVC project and it works fine. Can I use it in class library at all? If not how should I load this .json?

This is what I was actually doing inside:

```
public class Startup
{
    public AppSettings Settings { get; set; }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"config.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);

        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        Settings = new AppSettings();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        string connectionString;
        if (Configuration.TryGet("Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString", out connectionString))
        {
            Settings.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddInstance(Settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all?

Comment: @KnightFox Yes, I updated the question

Comment: Where are you putting up your DI? ConfigureServices is never called.

Comment: Did you find any answer for this? I am having the same problem

Comment: You can only have one Startup class in your Solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a second `Startup.cs` file because a class library is not a project that can startup. What you should do is take advantage of the dependency injection and add your DbContext to the services. Now when you need the DbContext for your repositories it'll be ready to go.

There is an example in the DI docs for Core http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html#using-framework-provided-services